# Change FreeBSD Loader's loaddev variable

Tags: freebsd

I'm searching the way to change `loaddev` variable of FreeBSD's `/boot/loader`. There is nothing useful either in FreeBSD's `man`, or in Google.

It's `disk0p2` by default which corresponds `GPT`, but also can be `disk0s2:` for `MBR` and `disk0a:` for BSD's disklabel and `disk0s2a:` for BSD disklabel (subpartition) on MBR's partition (aka slice).

But how to change it to load `loader.conf` from the partition I want?

When I try `set loaddev=disk0s2:` I get `operation not permitted`.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Splitting these two is conceptually not possible.

Machine firmwares pass information to bootstrap loaders ([in various ways](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/determining-boot-volume.html), the details of which are not important) giving the device paths for the boot volume.
Bootstrap loaders have to know that in order to find *anything*, including both the `/boot/loader` file and the `/boot/loader.conf` file, which are both files on the *same single* boot volume.

There's only one known volume at this point, as far as the loader is concerned, so there's no way to have these two files on two different volumes.

- In theory a conventional old-style [PC/AT bootstrap](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/pcat-boot-process.html) [boot manager](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/bootstrap-programs.html) could allow one to pick a different boot volume by selecting from that boot manager's menu.
- In theory one could rewrite the `BootXXXX` variable for the [EFI boot manager](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/efi-boot-process.html) to have a different device path in it.
- In theory, one could interrupt boot(8), gptboot(8), or gptzfsboot(8) at its spinner and type in the device path of the boot volume by hand.

In practice, these are fairly esoteric operations, and which one is even appropriate depends from what one's machine firmware is.
Multibooting, and all of the knowledge necessary to do it, is not as common as it once was.

And it changes the location of all of `/boot/loader`, `/boot/loader.conf`, and the kernel modules and files; all of which are on the same single boot volume.